# value noise random function strange output

Tags: c++, c, gcc, random, mingw

I am trying to implement this random function that I will use for Value Noise :

```
float random(int x, int y){
    int r;
    float s;

    srand(y*hgrid+x+seed);

    r=rand();

    s = (float)(r & 0x7fff)/(float)0x7fff;

    return (s);
}
```

As the author of this function said it ( https://code.google.com/p/fractalterraingeneration/wiki/Value_Noise ) :

> It is important to note that some compilers have their own RNG, so
>   this may not work for everyone. Visual C++ 2008 was especially
>   troublesome, however GCC on Linux works perfectly.

So I tried it on windows, using mingw. The output is really strange, since it gives me growing numbers from 0.0 to 1.0.

While on linux, it works like it should, random numbers from 0.0 to 1.0.

Since I am using mingw, which should be like gcc, I was expecting something working the same way.

Why doesn't it works? Is there a way to make it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why doesn't it works?

You're reseeding the random number generator each time, so each number is a simple function of that seed value. That appears to be what's wanted (so you get a consistent value for each location), but you don't want the function to be too simple.

It sounds like the mingw implementation returns the seed as the first generated number, while the linux implementation modifies it first.

> Is there a way to make it works?

Call `rand` more than once, to make sure you don't just get the seed value back. Or write your own calculation, perhaps based on a [common implementation of `rand`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator)

```
unsigned r = y*hgrid+x+seed;
r = r * 1103515245 + 12345;
return (float)(r & 0x7fff)/(float)0x7fff;
```

Comment: Indeed, calling rand 2 times gave me random numbers. Thanks!

Comment: That's not a particularly good generator.  The Park and Miller article cited by the Wiki article sets a standard for linear congruent algorithms, and though at the time, they found that most were lacking, in the more than 25 years which have passed, one would expect that library implementers would have switched to more reasonable variants.

Comment: I might add that you _never_ want your basic generator to return a float (although that is perhaps OK in the particular case of this question); returning a float makes it impossible to correct for the inherent bias when when you need a fixed number of concrete values.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Indeed, I was just providing an improvement over calling `rand()`, and didn't have time to research an unfamiliar problem domain to find the best solution.